# Хранение даты в Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

Подскажите в чем разница хранения даты между DateTime и Timestamp,и в чем лучше хранить!

Comment: timestamp - linux type, Datetime - Human type. Вопрос в чем лучше хранить, решать вам для каких целей в дальнейшем использовать данный параметр.

Comment: Ну вот у меня допустим есть поле где хранится дата когда юзер зарегался.На данный момент стоит тип Timestamp со значением current_timestamp,и если поменять на DateTime и так же заносить текущее время,разницы как я понял не будет?

Answer (score 2):

почитайте http://habrahabr.ru/post/61391/

Автор пояснил, что DATETIME не зависит от временной зоны, а TIMESTAMP при получении из базы отображается с учётом часового пояса

еще из статьи:

> DATETIME использует 8 байт, TIMESTAMP 4 байта
>
> TIMESTAMP по умолчанию NOT NULL, а его значение по умолчанию равно NOW()

в дополнение:
Есть вариант хранить его в int(11) 
http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2815&start=10